# How to create hash equivalent in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

Below snippet iterates & checks the container values which are greater than the defined value(100).
Container values are the output of an SQL query.

```
final=100
check=(`echo ${check} | sed 's/.*-//'`) # Array holding 5 entries

for i in "${check[@]}"
  do
    echo "Validating entries on: $i"

    num=`A SQL QUERY INVOLVING ARRAY ENTRIES [${i}] & RETUNS AN INTEGER`

    num=`echo ${num} | sed 's/.*-//'` # trims hyphens

    if [[ "${num}" > "${final}" ]]; then
          echo " num on ${i} didnt exceed the maximum: ${num}"
        else
          echo " num on ${i} under maximum: ${num}"
        fi
done
```

I'm looking to gather the values(${num}) which are greater than the threshold and send an email in below format:

```
echo -e "Container ${i}'s value has Exceeded threshold: ${num}" | mail -s "Prepare the cleanup scripts" <email_list>
```

But I'm not exactly sure how to produce an dictionary like format in Bash, similar to Python. I tried something like `mainA[${i}]="${num}"` and then

```
for i in "${!mainA[@]}"
  do
    echo "Count of $i
  done
```

but it returns only the container value not the container name. I need both conatiner name and its associated value.

Bash version - 4.2.46(2)-release

Comment: What version of bash are you using (`echo $BASH_VERSION`)? Bash support associative arrays. I'm not sure exactly when they were introduced, but I think it was 4.0. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html The syntax is a little tricky.

Comment: @KeithThompson : My bad, I should have provided that info. Its -- 
4.2.46(2)-release.
I'm kind of confused how to arrive at the conclusion.

Comment: Also notice that Bash supports string manipulation through parameter expansion. `${num##*-}` produces the value of `num` with all the text before the last hyphen removed.

Comment: Please choose a language with a proper SQL library and proper data structure support. `bash` simply is not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has built-in support for associative arrays, starting with release 4.0 (2011).

Bash arrays, both indexed and associative, are documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) -- or type `info bash`, go to "Bash Features", and then to "Arrays".

To define an associative array variable:

```
declare -A assoc
```

To set a value:

```
assoc[foo]=bar
```

To retrieve a value:

```
echo "${assoc[foo]}" # print "bar"
```

See the manual for other operations.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but not sure where I'm going wrong
`declare -A asArr
if [[ "${num}" > "${final}" ]]; then
          echo " num on ${i} didnt exceed the maximum: ${num}"
    asArr[$i]=$num
        else
          echo " num on ${i} under maximum: ${num}"
        fi
done

echo ${asArr[0]}`

prints an empty value

Comment: The code in your comment contains several errors and no values for `num` or `final`.

Comment: As for the last line, try `echo "${asArr[@]}"`, not `echo ${asArr[0]}`. In addition, compare numbers with `-gt` operator as `[[ $num -gt $final ]]` instead of `>`. `[[ $a > $b ]]` performs dictionary order comparison and the value `100` will be *smaller* than 2.